# Add Action To TextSelection in JTextPane

Tags: java, user-interface, jtextpane, textselection

I would like to add an action to textSelection in JTextPanel. It is easy to retrieve the selection, to highlight it, or add styles like bold or italic, however, I can' add an action to this selection. I would like to support simple actions (mouse action or any other simple action)... down is the code snippet to highlight the selection with a color... Any help is really appreciated

```
if (textPane.getSelectionStart()!=textPane.getSelectionEnd()){
        int e = textPane.getSelectionEnd();
        int s = textPane.getSelectionStart();
        String text = textPane.getSelectedText();
        //
          StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
          AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Background, Color.GREEN);
          textPane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
```

Comment: Do you want to add a listener to detect the clicks on the selection ? Or do you want to create a new action that will have an effect on the current selection ? Both are possible, but please, give more details about what you're trying to do.